# Liferay LDAP authentication ignoring password

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, liferay

I've configured an LDAP authentication on my Liferay Portal 6.2 CE.

The problem I figured out is that when users login, my portal ignore completely the password check.

This is the current user mapping:

```
UUID:
Username: sAMAccountName
Email: userPrincipalName
Password: unicodePwd
Name: givenName
Second name: middleName
Surname: sn
Fullname: cn 
Gruppo: memberOf
```

Moreover, the portal is configured to ignore Liferay internal password authentication, delegating to LDAP:

```
auth.pipeline.enable.liferay.check=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was mandatory to specify forcing ldap authentication flag as true. This configuration solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following two properties in portal properties extension file.

```
users.update.last.login=false
ldap.import.user.password.enabled=false
```

Restart you application container and then give it a try.

This is a pretty wild guess on my part because the problem is not well stated.  If the aforementioned changes do not work can you do the following.

1. Restate what is or is not currently working with explicit detail
2. State how you would like it to work
3. Post all of your portal override files
4. Post your entire app server console from when you start the server to when you try and log in

Post any other log entries pertaining to LDAP you think are important